# ProxyServlet with SSL

Tags: java, maven-2, ssl, jetty

I have some [proxy servlet](http://www.mortbay.org/xref/org/mortbay/servlet/ProxyServlet.html): [alt text http://img395.imageshack.us/img395/2770/capturei.png](http://img395.imageshack.us/img395/2770/capturei.png), and I want to make the connection(con A and con B on the diagram) to this servlet secure(with SSL). This proxy works under Maven Jetty Plugin.
I have configured jetty to handle ssl request:

```
 <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSocketConnector">
   <port>8443</port>
   <maxIdleTime>30000</maxIdleTime>
   <keystore>D:\Projekt\Proxy\keystore</keystore>
   <password>test</password>
   <keyPassword>test</keyPassword>
 </connector>
```

But when i try to go through this proxy (with browser), i have received an Exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? at 
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:523) at 
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:355) at 
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:789) at 
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1112) at 
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1139) at 
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1123) at 
org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSocketConnector$SslConnection.run(SslSocketConnector.java:631) at 
org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:520)
```

Where can be the problem, or how I can do it by another way?

Comment: Can you please post the full stacktrace? Also, is it originated from the User or from the proxy servlet?

Comment: It's from the proxy servlet,
from user(in browser): Data Transfer Interrupted